# TIPA package clashes with [T2A] for Cyrillic signs

Tags: font-encodings, linguistics, cyrillic, tipa

It appears that the TIPA package and the Cyrillic T2A fontenc-package cancel themselves out, only ever allowing the first defined package in the preamble to spell out in the document.

A friend needs both packages working for their thesis, however. Is there a way to either make these two compatible or to define new commands for a number of cyrillic signs (since there are only one or two needed there compared to multiple TIPA symbols)?

Here is the code that does not work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape}

\begin{document}

\exg. \textbf{učęštju} \textbf{emu} ljudi vъ crkve \label{ex:ucestju}\\
    teach-PrP.DAT.SG.   he-DAT. people-ACC.PL.  in  temple-LOC.SG.\\
    `While he was teaching people in the temple ...'\\
    (C. Mar. Lk. 20.1 from \citet[149]{lunt_old_2001})

\exg. $[$\textbf{hefði} þá verit þetta boðit$]$, þá væri margr maðr... \label{ex:hefditha}\\
    have-P.S.3sg.   then    be-PP.  this-NOM.SG.    offer-PP.NOM.SG.    then    be-P.S.3sg. many-NOM.SG.    man-NOM.SG.\\
    `Had this then been offered, then many a man would have been...’\\
    (Old Norse. Heimskringla 9.91, from Faarlund, 2007, 252)

\end{document}
```

We would need to define ъ in particular. \newcommand{\yer}{ъ} did not work, but unfortunately we cannot find any other way of defining cyrillic signs. Maybe through Unicode?

All help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to mix two scripts (latin and cyrillic) it is normally easier if you use an unicode engine like lualatex.

Comment: The `tipa` package has this glyph accessible via `\texthardsign`, so you could say `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044A}{\texthardsign}`.

Comment: Thank you all!!

Answer (score 2):

If you only need ъ, you should be able to access this glyph via the `\texthardsign` command provided by the [`tipa` package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/tipa/tipa/doc/tipaman.pdf).

If you want to keep this character in your code, you can set `\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044A}{\texthardsign}` in your document preamble (I'd suggest using `\textup` to revert to non-italic text instead of abusing math mode):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{044A}{\texthardsign}


\begin{document}

\exg. \textbf{učęštju} \textbf{emu} ljudi vъ crkve \label{ex:ucestju}\\
    teach-PrP.DAT.SG.   he-DAT. people-ACC.PL.  in  temple-LOC.SG.\\
    `While he was teaching people in the temple ...'\\
    (C. Mar. Lk. 20.1 from \citet[149]{lunt_old_2001})

\exg. \textup{[}\textbf{hefði} þá verit þetta boðit\textup{]}, þá væri margr maðr... \label{ex:hefditha}\\
    have-P.S.3sg.   then    be-PP.  this-NOM.SG.    offer-PP.NOM.SG.    then    be-P.S.3sg. many-NOM.SG.    man-NOM.SG.\\
    `Had this then been offered, then many a man would have been...’\\
    (Old Norse. Heimskringla 9.91, from Faarlund, 2007, 252)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This worked and I learned something new :)

Answer (score 2):

You get the error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \cyrhrdsn unavailable in encoding T1.
```

which you can solve by telling LaTeX that `\cyrhrdsn` must be taken from the T2A encoding, if found outside of Cyrillic contexts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper, total={6in, 8in}]{geometry}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{accents}
\usepackage{alphabeta}

\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
\usepackage{linguex}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\renewcommand{\eachwordone}{\itshape}

% declare the necessary encoding switch
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\cyrhrdsn}{T2A}

\begin{document}

\exg. \textbf{učęštju} \textbf{emu} ljudi vъ crkve \label{ex:ucestju}\\
    teach-PrP.DAT.SG.   he-DAT. people-ACC.PL.  in  temple-LOC.SG.\\
    `While he was teaching people in the temple ...'\\
    (C. Mar. Lk. 20.1 from \citet[149]{lunt_old_2001})

\exg. \textup{[}\textbf{hefði} þá verit þetta boðit\textup{]}, þá væri margr maðr...
      \label{ex:hefditha}\\
    have-P.S.3sg.   then    be-PP.  this-NOM.SG.    offer-PP.NOM.SG.    then 
      be-P.S.3sg. many-NOM.SG.    man-NOM.SG.\\
    `Had this then been offered, then many a man would have been...’\\
    (Old Norse. Heimskringla 9.91, from Faarlund, 2007, 252)

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This would render a nicer cursive version of the character in contrast to my approach.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Great, thank you!